# Cache backend system - xcache

Tags: cache

I want to use xcache as my cache backend system. All I do is add the following to local.xml:

```
<cache>
    <backend>xcache</backend>
    <prefix>username_</prefix>
</cache>
```

Is that it? I checked the file system. The cache is still stored over under /var/cache. I also found that the cache "Blocks HTML output" became invalid more easily.

Running Magento 1.9.1.

Comment: bad idea, use redis for cache backend, and zendopcache for php...

Comment: can you please explain more? I know redis is better, but using xcache is at least better than file system?

Comment: and with this configuration I can still see cache files generated into file system. I don't know if I configured it right....